# Difference between rdfs:seeAlso and rdfs:isDefinedBy

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs, linked-data

What is the difference between rdfs:seeAlso and rdfs:isDefinedBy?

When I can use rdfs:seeAlso and when I can use rdfs:isDefinedBy?

Can you do any examples for me?